# TextView measuring width correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am trying to create a custom ViewGroup by extending RelativeLayout.

I am adding some views on the parent layout drawing some bitmaps through `dispatchDraw` too.

Unfortunately, the TextView gets cut at the end and continues the rest of the text offscreen, so the next line is not correctly continued.

```
likesTextView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    likesTextView.setSingleLine(false);
    likesTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams likesParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    likesTextView.setLayoutParams(likesParams);

    addView(likesTextView);
```

These are the layout parameters i am using.

```
viewPager.layout(0,0,getWidth(),400);
    int finalWidth = 0;

    if((int) likesTextView.getPaint().measureText(finalLikesText) - r > 0){
        finalWidth = (int) likesTextView.getPaint().measureText(finalLikesText) - r + 100 + l;
    }else{
        finalWidth = getWidth();
    }

    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Final Width:" + finalWidth);
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),"MeasuredWidth:" + likesTextView.getMeasuredWidth() +
            " MeasuredHeight:" + likesTextView.getMeasuredHeight());
    likesTextView.measure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(likesTextView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(likesTextView.getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
    );
    likesTextView.layout(
            100,
            viewPager.getHeight(),
            100 + likesTextView.getMeasuredWidth(),
            likesTextView.getMeasuredHeight() + 400
    );
```

And this is the `onLayout` method where i set the width and height of it.

```
if (launcherBitmap != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(
                launcherBitmap,
                0,
                viewPager.getHeight(),
                photoPaint
        );
    }
    int x = 0, y = viewPager.getHeight() +
            likesTextView.getMeasuredHeight() + 80;
    for (String line: finalCommentsText.split("\n")) {
        canvas.drawText(line, x, y, commentsPaint);
        y += commentsPaint.descent() - commentsPaint.ascent();
    }
    if(launcherBitmap != null){
        int initialXUtilities = 0;
        canvas.drawBitmap(
                launcherBitmap,
                initialXUtilities,
                y + 10,
                photoPaint
        );

        canvas.drawBitmap(
                launcherBitmap,
                initialXUtilities + 100,
                y + 10,
                photoPaint
        );

        canvas.drawBitmap(
                launcherBitmap,
                initialXUtilities + 200,
                y + 10,
                photoPaint
        );
    }
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
```

This method is the `dispatchDraw` where i draw some bitmaps on the screen.

[image]

The result is this. As you can see in the right part of the screen the text is not properly continued between lines.

It's the first time i try to do something like this and i would appreciate some help if possible.

Have searched everything on the web but nothing i've found helped me out on this task.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you should be using [a `FlowLayout`](https://github.com/ismaeltoe/flowlayout), or something like that, as the container for the `TextViews`, where it will wrap them automatically. If that `FlowLayout` does not meet your needs, [here is another one](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout). And, if neither of those as quite what you want, you can use them for inspiration in writing your own.

Comment: Can i extend that too, or do i have to create an xml and wrap my elements?

Comment: It's a Java class, so presumably you can subclass them successfully.

Comment: @CommonsWare if I just add the textView to the flowLayout and then add the flowlayout to my RelativeLayout will have the same effect, right?

Comment: That's what I had in mind. Though it now dawns on me: is your comma-delimited list of links one big `TextView`? If yes, then that's not a `FlowLayout` scenario. You would use `FlowLayout` if, say, each word in the list was its own `TextView`. If the list of links is one large `TextView`,  your width calculations may be off. Use Hierarchy View or **`uiautomatorviewer`** to see how wide the `TextView` is. My apologies for not thinking straight -- it's still pretty early in the morning where I am... :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare The big text is just one TextView. Will try to use Hierarchy Viewer but how am i supposed to dynamically calculate the correct width?

Comment: Well, to be honest, ideally you wouldn't calculate it, but just let layout rules handle it for you. Based solely on the screenshot, to me, this is a simple case of a horizontal `LinearLayout`, wrapping an `ImageView` and a `TextView`, with `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` on the `TextView`, so it takes up all space not needed by the `ImageView`. There may be reasons why you are doing this all yourself, but then I don't have any great answers for your calculation issues.

Comment: @CommonsWare The android icon is drawn manually with `canvas.drawBitmap` and the textview is added to the relative layout. So i guess there are no layout rules.